# Using the output of `grep` as variable in second command

Tags: bash, command-line, variable, output

I currently have 2 bash command line strings I use to gather data needed for a certain task. I was trying to simplify and have only one command used to gather the data without using a script.

First I `cat` a file and pipe into a `grep` command and only display the integer value. I then copy and paste that value into an equation which will always be constant except for the `grep`ped value from the first command.

- 1st command:  `cat /proc/zem0 |grep -i isrs|grep -Eo '[0-9]+$'`
- 2nd command:  `echo $(( (2147483633-"**grep value**")/5184000 ))`

I'm stumped as to how I can accomplish this. Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is as one command:

```
echo $(( (2147483633 - $(grep -i isrs /proc/zem0 | grep -Eo '[0-9]+$') )/5184000 ))
```

#### How the simplification was done

First consider this pipeline:

```
cat /proc/zem0 |grep -i isrs`
```

This can be simplified to:

```
grep -i isrs /proc/zem0
```

Thus, the whole of the first command becomes:

```
grep -i isrs /proc/zem0 | grep -Eo '[0-9]+$'
```

The last change is to substitute the first command into the second using command substitution: `$(...)`.   Thus, we  replace:

```
echo $(( (2147483633-"**grep value**")/5184000 ))
```

with:

```
echo $(( (2147483633-$(grep -i isrs /proc/zem0 | grep -Eo '[0-9]+$'))/5184000 ))
```

#### One more simplification

If your `grep` supports perl-style regular expressions, such as GNU `grep`, then, as suggested by jimmij in the comments, one more simplification is possible:

```
echo $(( (2147483633-$(grep -Pio 'isrs.*?\K[0-9]+$' /proc/zem0))/5184000 ))
```

Comment: Even better to use only one `grep` with `perl` regexp: `echo $(( (2147483633-"$(grep -Pio 'isrs.*?\K[0-9]+$' /proc/zem0)")/5184000 ))`

Comment: @jimmij Excellent.  I added your idea to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, folks! This is very useful in helping me understand.

Comment: Hey gents, I tried applying the above solution and am getting a syntax error. Any idea what's happening?   -bash: (2147483633-"16463368")/5184000 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is ""16463368")/5184000 ")

Comment: @byron Hmmm.  I just revised the answer slightly.  Try it now.

Answer (score 0):

Use of command substitution as answered by John1024 is be best way to solve this problem.

Alternatively, you can pipe your output to `while read`, which will assign each space-separated value to a variable of your choosing. This is usually used when your output has more than one variable you'd like to use.

```
cat /proc/zem0 |grep -i isrs|grep -Eo '[0-9]+$' | while read myvariable ; do echo $(( (2147483633-"${myvariable}")/5184000 )) ; done
```

`while read` is really useful for columnar data, inserting stuff into inventory, etc. E.g. if `file1` content is:

```
host1 192.168.0.100 web nyc1 00-23-54-EE-10-5C
host2 192.168.0.101 web nyc2 00-23-54-EE-10-5D
host3 192.168.0.102 web nyc1 00-23-54-EE-10-5E
```

then you can do

```
cat file1 | while read host ip role dc mac ; do
    cobbler system add --name=${host} --ip-address=${ip} --netmask=255.255.255.0 --mac-address=${mac} --comments="${role} ${dc}"
done
```